# Finding element in jquery post data and updating the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, dom

I have an HTML markup like this:

```
@if (ViewBag.Added != null)
{
    if (ViewBag.Added == false)
    {                        
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="wholeBtn">
            <a class="btn btn-app btnWatchList" style="min-width:175px;margin:0;height:67px">
                <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Add to Watchlist
            </a>
        </div>
    }
    else if (ViewBag.Added)
    {
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="addedToWatchList">
            <h4>Added to watchlist</h4>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Where ViewBag.Added is a variable that I use to check whether I have a corresponding record in my DB...

I have defined an on click event when the user clicks save button inside the popup that appears like this, and then I try to update the DOM:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnSaveWatchlist", function(event)
{
    StopLoading();

    if ($('#TextArea1').val() == "" || !$('#ratingSystem input').is(':checked'))
    {
        ShowErrorMessage("All fields are required!");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        $.post("/SearchCompetitor/SaveWatchList",
        {
            comment: $('#TextArea1').val(),
            rating: $('input[name=rating]:checked').val(),
            competitor: $('.txtSearch').val()
        }).done(function(data)
        {
            if (data == "AllFieldsRequired")
            {
                ShowErrorMessage("All fields are required!");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                $("#wholeBtn").hide();
                var header = $('<div />').append(data).find('#addedToWatchList').html();
                $('#addedToWatchList').html(header);
                var l = document.getElementById('cancelButton');
                l.click();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Please note how I update the DOM itself:

```
$("#wholeBtn").hide();

var element = $('<div />').append(data).find('#addedToWatchList').html();

$('#addedToWatchList').html(element);
```

And this is the logic from server method:

```
public ActionResult SaveWatchList(string comment, string rating, string competitor)
{
    if (comment == "" || rating == "" || competitor == "")
        return Json("AllFieldsRequired");
    else
    {
        var user = ctx.Users.Where(x => x.Email == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();

        var uwl = new UserWatchList() 
        { 
            Comment = comment, 
            Rating = Int32.Parse(rating), 
            Type = 0, 
            SellerFeedback = Int32.Parse(Session["score"].ToString()), 
            SentWord = competitor, 
            UserId = user.UserId 
        };

        ctx.UserWatchList.Add(uwl);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        ViewBag.Added = true;

        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

The output that I'd like to have is to display the html is:

```
else if (ViewBag.Added)
{
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="addedToWatchList">
        <h4>Added to watchlist</h4>
    </div>
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

P.S. Note that when everything went well I return the whole HTML of the page via `Return View("Index");`

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this did the trick:

```
  var header = $('<div />').append(data).find('#addedToWatchList').html();
                                 $('#wholeBtn').html(header).show();
                                 var l = document.getElementById('cancelButton');
                                 l.click();
```

Turns out it was a bad idea to hide the element, instead I simply update the original one which fulfilled the if statemnt upon loading the page, and voila, works like a charm!